# If a supreme court judge makes a constitution violation sentence, are those who follows it violating the law, or those who follows the constitution?

Tags: constitutional-law

If a supreme court judge makes a sentence which violates the constitution, who is violating the law, those who follows the sentence, or those who follows the  constitution? Can people in executive power positions be judged later, in other governments or under other judges, for violating the constitution, even if they were following the sentence of a supreme court judge? And how about the judge himself, can he be judged?

Comment: there are way too many questions here

Comment: Supreme court judges don't make sentences. Trial court judges hand down sentences, and the Supreme Court hands down rulings. Rulings and sentences (in the legal sense) contain sentences (in the linguistic sense). Sentences in the linguistic sens are neither constitutional not unconstitutional. So basically, the question makes no sense.

Comment: @user6726 I think the question is just a misunderstanding of how the SCOTUS works

Comment: @user6726 if the question would say, "If a supreme court justice makes a constitution violation ruling, are those who follows the ruling violating the law, or those who follows the constitution?" would the question makes sense to you?

Comment: I can clarify with an example if needed. This is an often returning question in my country

Answer (score 2):

> If a supreme court judge makes a sentence

It wouldn't be *a Supreme Court Judge*, it would be *the Supreme Court Justices*, they have to come to a majority decision.

> a sentence which violates the constitution

The Constitution is interpreted by the Supreme Court so the conclusions they come to become "the law of the land" (I use that phrase loosely).

> Can people in executive power positions be judged later, in other governments or under other judges, for violating the constitution

Other governments don't recognize the US Constitution as the law of the land, so no, someone won't be tried in another country under the US Consitution.

Could they be tried by another government for breaking that government's law? I couldn't find any history of a person at an executive-level position being tried in another country. (feel free to edit this part if you know of any examples).

Someone in that position could be tried in the [International Criminal Court](https://www.icc-cpi.int/) but that also depends on what you mean by "Executive".

> how about the judge himself, can he be judged?

Just as if the President committed a crime, a Supreme Court Justice can be [Impeached](https://www.supremecourt.gov/about/faq_general.aspx)

Comment: I meant other future government, not a foreign government

Comment: It is "justices" not "judges".  And a president does not need to commit a crime to be impeached.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite you're right about the justice part, my bad, but to be Impeached and removed there has to be a conviction. If you want to argue that it doesn't have to be a crime that's fine but the language used in Impeachment "charged" and "conviction" implies a criminal nature

Comment: @Pablo if Nixon wasn't pardoned by Ford he would have been "Judged" by a future government.

Comment: Misuse of the power of the presidency would be a prime example of an impeachable act - there is no law against it so it would not be a crime.

Comment: @Pablo some people in executive positions tried by other countries: Herman Goering, Albert Spear, Slobodan Milosavic

Comment: @GeorgeWhite the US Constitution actually lays out what an impeachable act is. **Constitutional requirements for Impeachment:** "Treason, Bribery, or other high crimes and misdemeanors" these are the four *legal* reasons for impeachment, other theories of impeachment that aren't *legal* theories fit better into political theories of what impeachment is.

Comment: This is correct. It is similar to asking about what happens when an unstoppable force meets an impenetrable barrier. You can't grant a court authority to determine constitutionality and then claim that it has acted unconstitutionally.